# How getResources().getString() works in Java

Tags: java, android

I have just decompiled an apk file successfully with dex2jar and jd-gui tools and found some Android Java Source Code in that decompiled code.
 I found one line as following

```
String str = getResources().getString(2131034115);
```

I can't understand this line. What exactly does the variable str contain?

Answer (score 1):

What don't you understand? getString(x) is just returning the string at the resource id, and then that value is being saved into the String variable str...

Comment: You have to derive that from the resources of the application, In particular the R.java ids for particular resource. Which the decompiling may or may not have been able to retrieve...

Comment: In Generally where can i find resources in apk files

Comment: You do realize that an APK is a binary right? I'm unsure if you can grab the resources from an APK if it can't be resolved, chances are if you can't find the res directory then you are flat our of luck.

Answer (score 0):

getResources().getString(..) is fetching a string resource from the file strings.xml. It takes the id if the string as a parameter. Essentially it is an autogenerated integer from the R file.

In your own code you would write something like this

```
String str = getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world);
```

I suggest to use Eclipse and ADT and to create a new Android project to learn about the file structure and the different folders. Or reading more at [Android developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html).